# How to use design pattern to solve grouping collection with rules?

Tags: design-patterns

Suppose I have a collection of numbers, eg. A = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].

And several rules like:
a: number is multiple of 3;
b: number is multiple of 5;

With the rules, it's easy to split the original collection into three:

```
A_3 = [3, 6, 9, 12]
A_5 = [5, 10]
A_other = [2, 4, 7, 8, 11]
```

I am wondering the best way to design the classes of collection and rules to achieve the goals:

1. it's easy to add or decrease rules
2. the type of elements in the collection can be easily changed

Thanks.

Comment: Homework? You may need to tag it if it is a homework.

Comment: Would you prefer any specific language to handle this? Solving this in C# or VB.Net might require a different approach from solving it in for instance Clojure.

Comment: @Saintali It's not a homework. I am just thinking of it

Comment: @Kjartan I'm a web developer and think to implement in php. C# or VB.Net is also OK for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to me You should use [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) which is typically used when your  algorithm is interchangeable with different variations of the algorithm.

For example,

if you have code that creates an array like yours , under certain circumstances,
you might want to pick multiples of 3 and under other circumstances, you might
want to pick multiples of 5.

The strategy pattern is usually implemented as follows

Declare an abstract base class with an algorithm method, which is then implemented by inheriting concrete classes. At some point in the code, it is decided what concrete strategy is relevant , later it would then be instantiated and used wherever relevant.

I am not sure whether this serves your requirement .

I cant conclude that you can use only this , I always believe in [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to use C#, I would start off with something like this:

```
// General interface to filter out whatever you want, given a list:
public interface IFilterElements<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> elementList);
}


// An example imlementation - add more of these as required:
class FilterElementsThatAreEven<T> : IFilterElements<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> elementList)
    {
        // Some implementation to return a sorted set / list
    }
}
```

In your calling method, you could then do something like:

```
// List to filter
IEnumerable<int> myListOfInts = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

// Instantiation of the implementation - also where you specify the 
// type of data to filter (could be of class "MagicLemur" instead of int)
IFilterElements<int> myIntFilter = new FilterElementsThatAreEven<int>();

var filteredList = myIntFilter.FilterElementsThatAreEven();
```